# Reading and Writing Fifo Files between C and Python

Tags: python, c, file-io, fifo

In general, I am creating two fifo queues to be read and written to by my .c and .py programs. To enable my .c program to interact with python, I have included the `<python2.7/Python.h>` library.

Firstly, my .c program creates a file called CFifo and writes text to it using fprintf. No problem there.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <python2.7/Python.h>


int main() {
    FILE *CFifo, *pythonFifo, *pythonFile;
    char buffer[1024];

    // declare python
    Py_SetProgramName("writer.py");

    // init python
    Py_Initialize();

    // open python
    pythonFile = fopen("writer.py", "r");

    // C writes to file, python reads from this file
    CFifo = fopen("./CFifo", "w");  

    // Print strings to file using fprintf
    fprintf(CFifo, "This is a test");

    // close file python reads
    fclose(CFifo);
```

The second part of my C program should read the information written (in the second fifo queue) by my python program but instead it just hangs in the terminal when opening `./pythonFifo`.

```
    // make second fifo queue
    // python writes to this file, C reads from it
    mkfifo("./pythonFifo", 0777);

    // run python program
    PyRun_SimpleFile(pythonFile, "writer.py");
    pythonFifo = fopen("./pythonFifo", "r");

    while(fgets (buffer, sizeof(buffer), pythonFifo)) {
        printf("%s", buffer);
    }

    // close python
    Py_Finalize();
    fclose(pythonFifo);
    remove("./pythonFifo");

    return 0;
}
```

This is the python section responsible for writing to the fifo queue.

```
# open fifo file that python writes to
filename_write = "./pythonFifo"
pipe = os.open(filename_write, os.O_WRONLY)
for output in finalStringList:
   os.write(pipe, output)
os.close(pipe)
```

The purpose of the second file is to write modified information read from the first file.

Answer (score 1):

You can't get there from here. From the `mkfifo` man page...

> Once  you have created a FIFO special file in this way, any process
>   can open it for reading or writing, in the same way as  an  ordinary 
>   file. However,  it  has to be open at both ends simultaneously before
>   you can proceed to do any input or output operations on it.  Opening a
>   FIFO for reading  normally  blocks  until some other process opens the
>   same FIFO for writing, and vice versa.

Both sides need to open the file before they can continue. But since `PyRun_SimpleFile` runs a python script sychronously, the latter C code that opens the file is never reached. If you try to open it in the C code first, it would hang before running the python code. You have a classic deadlock.

I added several prints to your sample and was able to see the program advance as I did `cat pythonFifo` and `echo foo > pythonFifo` in a separate console. It returned garbage of course, but proved the problem.

Actually, you can get there from here (again, the man page)

> See fifo(7) for nonblocking  handling  of FIFO special files.

but you open yourself to more deadlocking if your python code writes more than fits in the pipe. You may be better off having your python program write to some variable and have your C code read it from there.

Comment: How about suggesting to run the Python program asynchronously?  Wouldn't that be the "natural" way of solving this deadlock?

Comment: @Alfe - that could be a great way to do it but I don't see how its the more natural way. It all depends on other design issues we don't know about.

Comment: I assumed this `PyRun_SimpleFile` starts a new process to perform the Python stuff, then explicitly waits for the termination of the child process.  More "natural" would just be not to wait because we all are using operating systems which run processes in parallel.  Your response alienated me, however.  Is the `PyRun_SimpleFile` maybe running its task within the current process?  Then using fifos would probably be the wrong choice in general.

Comment: I read about this `PyRun_SimpleFile` and now understand the situation better.  I'd propose to abandon the idea to communicate via fifos if we are not using different processes (or at least threads which I don't see here as well).  I'd propose to use different means like data structures accessible from both sides, Python and C (which was your last sentence, as I saw when re-reading it).

Comment: @Alfe - Yeah, its an embedded python interpreter and runs inline with the other code. Your ideas are good... OP could for instance use threads or multiprocessing in the python script... but its more complicated. Whether its better, I don't know!

Comment: Fifo is a means for interprocess communication (and a rather crude one, I'd say, with lots of drawbacks like security, handling, file system dependencies, etc.).  If you don't have multiple processes I'd say it is wrong—like using an elevator to travel from town to town.  You could probably build a horizontal one, it would still be wrong ;-)